# How to implement `Iterator` for a resizing array stack using `NonNull`?

Tags: rust, iterator

I am following the [guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/vec/vec.html) to implement a resizing array stack using `NonNull`:

```rust
pub struct ResizingStack<T> {
    a: NonNull<T>,
    n: usize,
    capacity: usize,
}
```

Now the basic functionalities (e.g., `push` and `pop`) work well. The complete code can be found [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=833873c35d0882d57061d37678a0d0b3). But I have some troubles in implementing the `Iterator` trait.

For a *forward* iterator, a simple solution is to make `ResizingStack` coerce to, and behave like, a `slice`.

```rust
impl<T> Deref for Vec<T> {
    type Target = [T];
    fn deref(&self) -> &[T] {
        unsafe {
            std::slice::from_raw_parts(self.a.as_ptr(), self.n)
        }
    }
}
```

However, a stack, in fact, should have a *backward* iterator. The followings are my attempts:

```rust
pub struct StackIter<'a, T> {
    buf: &'a ResizingStack<T>,
    index: usize,
}

impl<T> ResizingStack<T> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> StackIter<'_, T> {
        StackIter {
            buf: self,
            index: self.n,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for StackIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            let item;
            unsafe {
                item = Some(ptr::read(self.buf.a.as_ptr().add(self.index - 1)));
                self.index -= 1;
            }
            item // ERROR: expected `Option<&T>`, but found `Option<T>`.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that `type Item = &'a T;` promises to return *references*, but `ptr::read` returns the actual *value*.

Comment: The immediate fix for the type issue would be to replace `item = Some(ptr::read(...))` with `item = Some(&*self.buf.a.as_ptr().add(self.index - 1))`. But the answer shows better ways to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: In other words, `ptr::read()` is much more destructive than the name suggests - it performs what (in Rust terminology) is known as **move**, and is only appropriate when you own the underlying object (which you do) and when you don't plan to use it anymore (which is not the case in your code). For example, you'd use `ptr::read()` to implement `into_iter()` or `drain()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use `unsafe` code for an iterator that yields `&T`.

Here's a solution that uses [`.split_last()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_last):

```
pub struct StackIter<'a, T> {
    buf: &'a [T],
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for StackIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let (last, remainder) = self.buf.split_last()?;
        self.buf = remainder;
        Some(last)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's a solution that wraps [`.rev()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev):

```
use std::{iter::Rev, slice};

pub struct StackIter<'a, T> {
    inner: Rev<slice::Iter<'a, T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for StackIter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.inner.next()
    }
}
```

At this point, we may as well ditch the wrapper and return the adapter directly:

```
impl<T> ResizingStack<T> {
    pub fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T> {
        self.deref().iter().rev()
    }
}
```

Comment: You provide three solutions, and I really want to give you THREE thumbs up votes :)

Comment: Marking the answer as "accepted" if you really appreciate it and find no way to upvote more. :) That will also let others know there is an accepted answer to the question.